# WebSphere Liberty Eclipse won't publish application to apps directory

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

I have a 4-project, Maven-based EAR application (JavaEE-7.0) with a parent, WAR, resources, and EAR project. I am using Eclipse Oxygen with the latest release of WAS Liberty 17.0.0.2 and the latest release of the WAS Liberty plugin for Eclipse Oxygen.

I have no error markers anywhere in any of my files and Maven can produce an EAR.

When I try to publish to Liberty, nothing happens. I've done all number of possible cleans: workspace cleans, Liberty server clean, Maven clean, etc. but even though the server says `[Synchronized]`, *nothing ever shows up in the apps directory* of my server.

The server is locally hosted on Windows 10 and I'm using JRE 8u141.

When WLP starts up, it says `CWWKZ0014W: The application foo could not be started as it could not be found at location blah.ear.`

I've tried nuking my WLP installation and reinstalling from scratch; still no dice.

(Cue rant about tools keeping me from getting work done...)

**How can I resolve this?**

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the Add/Remove dialog from the Servers view to publish the EAR to the server? This works for me using my sample maven EAR project.

A few things to check:

- EAR project's Deployment Assembly page references the other projects
- The WebSphere Application Server Liberty Targeted Runtime is checked on the Targeted Runtimes properties page for each of the projects
- Project > Build Automatically is turned on (or you've done a Build All) in your workspace
- Your server's server.xml should contain an 'enterpriseApplication' element after the publish

If the publish still doesn't work, can you provide more details about your EAR's pom as well as how you created the project. (using an archetype? based off of a sample? converted an existing EAR project to a maven project?)